# ngTagsInput autocomplete show suggestions on click

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I would like to customize the style and behaviour of autocomplete to resemble a button. The main issue is that autocomplete currently can show suggestions on-down-arrow, on-focus and on-empty.

Any pointers to implement this? Any alternative modules that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

directive tagsInput is defined as

```
tagsInput.directive('tagsInput', function($timeout, $document, tagsInputConfig) {
...
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        tags: '=ngModel',
        onTagAdded: '&',
        onInvalidTag: '&',
        onTagRemoved: '&'
    },
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'ngTagsInput/tags-input.html',
```

It will load `ngTagsInput/tags-input.html` as its template. Then let's take a look at this [file](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/templates/tags-input.html)

```
<input class="input"
       ng-model="newTag.text"
       ng-change="eventHandlers.input.change(newTag.text)"
       ng-keydown="eventHandlers.input.keydown($event)"
       ng-focus="eventHandlers.input.focus($event)"
       ng-blur="eventHandlers.input.blur($event)"
       ng-paste="eventHandlers.input.paste($event)"
       ng-trim="false"
       ng-class="{'invalid-tag': newTag.invalid}"
       ti-bind-attrs="{type: options.type, placeholder: options.placeholder, tabindex: options.tabindex, spellcheck: options.spellcheck}"
       ti-autosize>
```

So you can add your customized action `ng-click="eventHandlers.input.click($event)"` here and implement the click function in directive.

Customizing styles should be similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried it yet, but came up with a solution that modifies the autocomplete directive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by Rebornix, I ended up forking and modifying the autocomplete directive with a new loadOnClick parameter that will call suggestionList.load().

Some more fine-tuning might be needed, but it works as expected. The changes are committed as follows: [event handler - template](https://github.com/emiguevara/ngTagsInput/commit/3ca413ec0ae6ec4987cf4bcc297af60448710302) and [implementation](https://github.com/emiguevara/ngTagsInput/commit/b2227f3b2d9817a802c5c0d80c1838d61e10edeb).